# figure position in using baposter

Tags: baposter

I am usign the `baposter` enviroment to create a scientific poster. My question is that I am attaching images of different sizes in

```
\begin{center}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.18]{fig1.pdf}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.22]{fig1a.pdf}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.22]{fig2a.pdf}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.22]{fig2b.pdf}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.22]{fig2c.pdf}
   \captionof{figure}{\tiny{}}
\end{center}
```

and the issue is that I would like to put the figures `fig2x.pdf` a little bit higher compared to where they are (such that the space between the text and these set of figures is lesser compared to the other two figures).

Comment: It would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem. While solving problems can be fun, setting them up is not. Then, those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving the problem.

Comment: And can you maybe draw a sketch or something to show us how the output should look like? From your question it is totally unclear to me.

Comment: currently all we know is that you have five figures in a line with one word space between each. TeX's paragraph breaker may or may not have wrapped that line into one or more lines depending on how wide the figures are and how wide your text block is, but you have given no information.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. Basically the problem is that the images does not have the same size, so arranging them in a row all of them are set to the bottom. In short I will give the preamble of the document.

Comment: Add `\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}` and use `\includegraphics[valign=m,scale=0.22]{file}` instead.